# Is there a way to make Magento indexing more intelligent?

Tags: magento, indexing

I would like like to know if it is possible to make a new method to only update indexes on products which have changed since I run a store with 206000 records in the core_url_rewrite table and need to update product status everyday.

It takes 8 hours using a CLI call to index.php --reindex catalog_url.

Comment: first you need to ask why you have such amount of rewrites and get a better hosting environment would be the second suggestion

Comment: 1200 products in 3 categories in 127 websites = 400,000 sql records needed

Comment: then i would suggest 127 separate storefronts and one website and global products then only 1200 records needed. Other way is to extend the url rewrite methods to use only one website urls

Comment: Yes I would suggest this too, normally, but in this case there is too much custom code gone into supporting the structure already.

Comment: well , time to restructure :) as you can do it in parallel with current structure still running. I suggest a quick php script that creates storefronts and sets needed settings. Bad design decisions have their price as customizing it more will take you even further from normal situation

Comment: As long as the indexer mode is set to "Update on Save", Magento will reindex only the needed products on save in most cases. What operation do you do that triggers a index rebuilding warning?

Comment: Restructure is too big a task at this stage - too far down the road to turn back now :)

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the `catalog_product_save_after` event and update individual rows as they need updating, that way you won't have to perform full indexing everyday. Actually this is what's supposed to already happen so think, what are you doing that breaks this?

Comment: The products get imported from another system every day at a DB level

Comment: I suppose that would be a problem. Can you update the index tables directly too at the same time?

Comment: I dont quite follow your question?

Comment: When adding a new product via SQL try to insert the same/relevant data into each of the `catalog_product_flat_XX` tables `core_url_rewrite` and anywhere else the indexer works. That way the re-indexing isn't needed as often. I'm not saying it's easy to work all that out but it is a closed system so must be possible.

Comment: Yes I like that approach, thats just the kind of answer I was looking for. IN fact I opened a question about getting a list of tables used in the indexing process, but noone seemed to know.   Could I perhaps setup a mysql log somehow to see which tables where affected when I process the index?   Thanks Clockwork for your help so far.

Comment: As a clumsy way of finding out you could make a small store with one or two products/categories, do a database dump, run the index, do another database dump and diff the two results. That should show which tables are being changed but not necessarily in an easy to read way.